# calculate every pairwise quotient of a list of vectors in a dataframe, store as a new object in R

Tags: r

Say I have 4 vectors, in data frame `datt`:

```
a<-rnorm(10,30)
b<-rnorm(10,20)
c<-rnorm(10,40)
d<-rnorm(10,100)
datt<- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

I then have a list of vectors within the dataframe:

```
list<-c(a,b,c)
```

I'd like to calculate every pairwise quotient of vectors within the dataframe that are included in my list. so `a/b`, `a/c`, and `b/c`, and store those vectors as a new dataframe or array. Bonus if the names of the columns in the new array are `a.b`,`a.c`,`b.c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this works:

```
# alternate naming
L <- list(a=a,b=b,c=c)
# or even easier
L <- datt[c("a","b","c")]

res <- combn(L, 2, function(x) x[[1]]/x[[2]])
```

To assign names...

```
colnames(res) <- apply(combn(names(L),2),2,paste,collapse=".")
```

With `set.seed(1)` before drawing sample data, this gives:

```
           a.b       a.c       b.c
 [1,] 1.365463 0.7178465 0.5257165
 [2,] 1.480327 0.7401192 0.4999700
 [3,] 1.504966 0.7277527 0.4835676
 [4,] 1.776483 0.8312218 0.4679031
 [5,] 1.435721 0.7466676 0.5200645
 [6,] 1.462262 0.7305134 0.4995777
 [7,] 1.525606 0.7651660 0.5015487
 [8,] 1.467655 0.7977920 0.5435828
 [9,] 1.468491 0.7736425 0.5268281
[10,] 1.441913 0.7346889 0.5095238
# for comparison
> datt$a/datt$b
 [1] 1.365463 1.480327 1.504966 1.776483 1.435721 1.462262 1.525606
 [8] 1.467655 1.468491 1.441913
```

As suggested by @akrun, it is not necessary to run `combn` twice:

```
do.call('data.frame', combn(L, 2, simplify = FALSE, FUN = function(x) 
  setNames(list(x[[1]]/x[[2]]), paste(names(x), collapse=':')) 
))
```

Comment: I only want to calculate the quotients of a-c based on `list`, not a-d.

Comment: Okay, by the way, please don't name things `list`, since that is a very commonly used function. Nor `c` for that matter.

Comment: Or `do.call('data.frame',combn(L, 2, function(x) list(setNames(list(x[[1]]/x[[2]]), paste(names(x), collapse=':')))))`

Comment: Thanks, @akrun . Added